# Perfect Column Equation C++

Tags: c++, string, multiple-columns, output

I have an application that lets the user enter a string. I then count the string and put the number of characters next to it. The problem comes when I want put it in columns such as:

```
This is a Sentence                      The Len is 18
This is Another Sentence                The Len is 24
A                                       The Len is 1
```

How would I calculate the setw() of the columns? str.size() and then something else I can't get it exactly right it's always wobbley.

Comment: What is problem with finding the max size value and use it + 10 symbols?

Comment: not sure what you mean - but if I add just 10 symbols to the original string it will be off

Comment: Do you print word exactly after input? Or user inputs, say 10 words, then you print them

Comment: I print them down the line. There's more input then I print the output at the very end but I want to print it nice and neat.

Comment: Just checking, since you are talking about "wobbley", are you sure you are using a console with monospaced font ? :)

Comment: By "wobbley" I just mean 'off' / not aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need calc max word length, then you need to align output text with max length.
Something like

```
int align = maxWordSize - curWord.size();
for(int i = 0; i < align; i++)cout << " ";
```

Or did i misunderstood something?

Comment: That worked - but is there no other like printf or setw. I mean that works but is it the most efficient.

Comment: In stl - no. If you can use boost - there is Boost.Format with column align feature.
_New formatting feature : 'absolute tabulations', useful inside loops, to insure a field is printed at the same position from one line to the next, even if the widthes of the previous arguments can vary a lot._

Comment: @kuperspb This is doing things the hard way.  Why not use `std::setw` (which works like a charm here)?

Answer (score 1):

In this case max length of the string entered by the user is not defined and can vary so you can either assume the max length for your self and can set the space by simple calculation.

if we assume that our entered string would not exceed a certain limit then we can fix the position for the length column as follows by lenghtCol_pos and can calculate stw as follows:

```
int lenghtCol_pos = 15;

string str ("Test string");

cout<<str<<stw( lenghtCol_pos-str.size() )<<"The Len is "<<str.size()<<endl;
```

While on the hand if user is free to add as much long string he can then we can store all the strings in a 2d array and then can get the max length of the string and can set the setw() accordingly.

Comment: What is `stw`?  And where does the 2D array come from: I only see an `std::vector`.  Any other choice is simply bad programming.

Answer (score 0):

To align things like this, you first have to collect all of the strings
in memory, probably in an `std::vector<std::string>`.  You can then use
`std::max_element` to find the longest, with a comparison function like:

```
struct CompareSize
{
    bool operator()( std::string const& lhs, std::string const& rhs ) const
    {
        return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
    }
};
```

Afterwards, you can set the `adjustfield` formatting parameter of the
output stream, and then use `std::setw` when you iterator over the 
strings, outputting each with something like:

```
size_t longest = std::max_element( data.begin(), data.end(), CompareSize() )->size();
std::cout.setf( std::ios_base::left, std::ios_base::adjustfield );
for ( std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator current = data.begin(), end = data.end();
        current != end;
        ++ current ) {
    std::cout << std::setw( longest ) << *current
              << " The length is "
              << current->size()
              << std::endl;
```

(In actual code, of course, you'd want to save the initial value of the
flags, and restore it after having finished the loop.  Otherwise, the
change to the `adjustfield` will have somewhat surprising results on any
numeric output which might follow.)